# zsh (MacOS): Loop through list of apps and open them

Tags: macos, terminal, zsh

Just starting out w/ zsh scripting, and have run into an issue I'm not sure how to resolve. Here is a basic function that opens a selection of apps when executed:

```
workPlace () {  
    for app in Slack Docker “Google Chrome” “GitHub Desktop”
        do open -a $app
    done
}

workPlace
```

The function executes, but does not open applications with 'Multi Word' name:

```
Unable to find application named '“Google'
Unable to find application named 'Chrome”'
Unable to find application named '“GitHub'
Unable to find application named 'Desktop”'
```

I have tried creating a list of string vals to loop through, but this also fails.

Any help would be appreciated

Comment: You have fancy ("smart") double-quotes instead of plain ASCII quotes. The shell doesn't recognize them as functional quotes.

Comment: Single quotes returns the same error.

Comment: Are they also the fancy curved quotes? Compare plain ASCII quotes: `'` and `"` vs fancy Unicode quotes: `“`, `”`, `‘`, and `’`. The shell only recognizes plain ones. [shellcheck.net](https://www.shellcheck.net) will point this problem out (although it's really set up for bash and plain sh, some some of its warnings aren't applicable to zsh scripting).

Answer (score 0):

Solved: Required single quotes:

```
    . . .for app in Slack Music Docker 'Google Chrome' 'GitHub Desktop'. . .
```

Thanks to Gordon Davisson in the comments.